# Looking for a solution to compare specific output from ls and only print the non-matching lines (ksh)

Tags: ksh

Fairly new to scripting, and I apologize if this has been exhausted, but I've searched and haven't really found a solution.

I'm using ksh, and need to compare some data in order to exclude it.

```
root@ aixtest /dev
#ls -l /dev/hdisk*
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  1 Apr 12 2013  /dev/hdisk0
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  0 Apr 12 2013  /dev/hdisk1
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  3 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk2
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  2 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk3
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  4 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk4
root@ aixtest /dev
#ls -l /dev/ORA*
crw-r--r--    1 root     system       18,  3 Jan 14 16:58 /dev/DATA00
crw-r--r--    1 root     system       18,  4 Jan 14 16:58 /dev/DATA01
```

What I'm looking to do, is compare major and minor numbers between the hdisk* and DATA* sets, and print the non-matching data, specifically just hdiskN. So, with the above as an example, I'm just looking to get something this this -

```
hdisk0
hdisk1
hdisk3
```

This is needed to compare and exclude disks that are already in use by something else. The old method was to use `lspv` and then exclude the active disks, but with these, in particular, they won't show as active even when in use, so an alternative method was needed.

---

I ended up using this:

```
ls -ld /dev/DATA* /dev/hdisk* | 
    awk '{print $5, $6, $10}' | sort | 
    awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -u -f1 | 
    awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^\/dev\///g' | sort
```

Comment: What will you use this for?  It looks like you're actually looking for the block devices (prefix `b`) that corresponds to a list of specified raw devices (with prefix `c`).  Or do you actually need the one on one mapping for each device?

Comment: I ended up using this - 

`ls -ld /dev/DATA* /dev/hdisk* | awk '{print $5, $6, $10}' | sort | awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -u -f1 | sort | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^\/dev\///g' | sort` 

This was to compare and exclude disks that were already in use by something else. The old method was to use `lspv` and then exclude the active disks, but with these, in particular, they won't show as active even when in use, so an alternative method was needed.

Comment: The middle `sort` in there was a typo; the edit session expired.

Comment: I've copied your own solution to the question, but I recommend that you copy that into an answer of your own. Meanwhile, I've provided a solution with less pipelines below. ;-)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm still getting used to the site!

Answer (score 0):

```
A=/dev/hdisk*
B=/dev/ORA*
ls -lL $A $B | while read perm n u g maj min d1 d2 d3 file
do
    echo "$file $maj $min"
done | sort -k2,3 | uniq -u -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Src1=/dev/hdisk*
Src2=/dev/DATA*

ls -l ${Src1} ${Src2} | sed -n 's|^\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{5\}\([0-9]*\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}/dev/|\2 |
H
$ {
  x
  s/$/\
/
: again
  s/\(\n\)\([0-9]*\) [^[:cntrl:]]*\(.*\)\n\2 [^[:cntrl:]]*\n/\1\3\1/
  t again
  s/\(\n\)\{2,\}/\1/g
  s/[0-9]* DA.*$//
  p
  }'
```

not sorted (just the `ls` sort)

PS: ls /dev/ORA* does not give list like /dev/DATA00  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional comments, here's a solution in `awk` that used
compound array indexes.

First, I'll need a mock function to emulate your `ls -l` command:

```
lsdisks() {
    cat <<END
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  1 Apr 12 2013  /dev/hdisk0
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  0 Apr 12 2013  /dev/hdisk1
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  3 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk2
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  2 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk3
brw-------    1 root     system       18,  4 Jan 14 15:52 /dev/hdisk4
crw-r--r--    1 root     system       18,  3 Jan 14 16:58 /dev/DATA00
crw-r--r--    1 root     system       18,  4 Jan 14 16:58 /dev/DATA01
END
}
```

Then follows a solution with a single `awk` script, wrapped in a function:

```
skip_matching_disks() {
    awk -F '[ /]+' '{ major=$5; minor=$6; devname=$NF; }
    /^b/ { blockname[major,minor]=devname }
    /^c/ { rawname[major,minor]=devname }
    END { 
        for (numbers in blockname) 
            if (!rawname[numbers])
                print blockname[numbers]
    }' | sort
}

pipeline() {
    awk '{print $5, $6, $10}' | sort |
        awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -u -f1 | 
        awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/^\/dev\///g' | sort
}

print "single awk solution: "
lsdisks | skip_matching_disks 

print "OP solution:"

lsdisks | pipeline
```

I've included your original solution for easy comparison.